# Something like AJAX in Flash?

Tags: ajax, flash, actionscript

How can we get data from the server in an asynchronous way in Flash? I am looking for something like XHR in actionscript.

Comment: Can you please point me to an example where loader is used to get JSON like data from server and then used like an array / object? Further, is it possible for the URL to point to a PHP file?

Comment: yes the URL can point to a php file. http://www.heaveninteractive.com/weblog/2008/03/17/using-actionscript-30-with-php-part-1/
There are tons more examples if you google. You can also either write a JSON parser yourself, or google for one.

Edit: looks like Les already posted what you needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [URLLoader class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary) you can request data from a server side script.

Personally I use JSON to communicate between server and flash (handy if you want to call the same scripts from javascript). There is a great library for decoding / encoding JSON strings in flash: http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/

```
package {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import com.adobe.serialization.json.*;

    class Test {
        private var loader:URLLoader;

        public function Test() {
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/api/myscript.py");
            loader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadData);

            try {
                loader.load(request);
            }catch (error:SecurityError) {
                trace("security error");
            }

        }

        private function onLoadData(e:Event) {
            var obj:Object = JSON.decode(e.target.data);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. You can send HTTP request to the server and set a callback. You can even use direct socket connections (in Flex at least).

Comment: Can you direct me to an example where an HTTP request / callback is used? How do we use the data returned? Can something like a JSON be returned which we can use directly as an object / array?